# How to close wx.DirDialog programmatically?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have wxpython app that open wx.DirDialog on button click.

```
dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        # Do some stuff
```

Since my application is multithreaded and uses wxTaskbaricon which allow user (on Win 7) to close application even when modal DirDialog is open, I want to close the DirDialog before closing main app. Somehow non of below method work:

```
dlg.Destroy()
dlg.Close(True)
```

Comment: Show more code. Do you use `self.dlg` to get access to `dlg` in all functions in class ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using self.dlg. None of its method able to close/destroy DirDialog programatically.

Comment: Probably you have to do it in appropriate thread - maybe in main thread or in thread where you created dialog. I tested `Destroy()`, `Close()` and `EndModal()` on non-threaded program and they work.

Comment: Maybe there is another possibility - accidentally `dlg` is `None`

Comment: Are you sure you created wx.DirDialog (not normal dialog window)?

Comment: I put my testing code below as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is my testing code.

I can test `Destroy()`, `Close()` and `EndModal()` on Modal and Non-Modal `wx.DirDialog()`

To close modal dialog I had to use Timer - because modal dialog is blocking access to the main window.

It can't close dialog only if I do

```
self.dlg = None
self.dlg.EndModal(wx.CANCEL) # or Destroy() or Close(True)
```

And one more thing - I use Linux Mint 15, Python 2.7.4, wxPython 2.8.12.1 :)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import sys # to get python version

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(600,100))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)


        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Python "+sys.version+"\nwxPython"+wx.version())
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="On")
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Off")

        self.sizer.Add(self.label)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.button2)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OpenDialog, self.button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CloseDialog, self.button2)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.TimerCloseDialog, self.timer)

        self.Show(True)

        self.dlg = None

    def OpenDialog(self, event):
        print "OpenDialog"

        self.timer.Start(3000, oneShot=True)
        print "wait 3s ..."

        if not self.dlg:
            self.dlg = wx.DirDialog(self)
            self.dlg.ShowModal()
            #self.dlg.Show(True)

    def CloseDialog(self, event):
        print "CloseDialog"
        if self.dlg:
            #self.dlg = None
            #self.dlg.EndModal(wx.CANCEL)
            self.dlg.Destroy()
            #self.dlg.Close(True)

    def TimerCloseDialog(self, event):
        print "TimerCloseDialog"
        if self.dlg:
            #self.dlg = None
            self.dlg.EndModal(wx.CANCEL)
            #self.dlg.Destroy()
            #self.dlg.Close(True)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

print "Python", sys.version
print "wxPython", wx.version()

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(None, "Hello Dialog")
app.MainLoop()
```