# wxpython - responding to MessageDialogs and FileDialogs within a frame during unit-testing

Tags: unit-testing, dialog, wxpython

I would like to test a GUI I have been working on written using wxpython without requiring interaction so that I can continue development and test regularly and easily. My problem is that whenever I test a function that opens a modal dialog the testing pauses and won't continue until I manually press the OK button. I can't seem to discover a reason for this, but it is connected to the native wxpython dialog types like wx.MessageDialog and wx.FileDialog because if I use show modal on a custom class that inherits from wx.Dialog then I can use wx.CallAfter to respond to the dialog fine. So is there a good way to respond to these modal dialogs?

The dialogs don't work during normal operation of the GUI if I just use Show instead of ShowModal so I can't simply not make the dialogs modal.

Bellow is a bit of code to test this outlining this basic problem. It runs two tests one that opens a wx.MessageDialog and one that opens a custom dialog both I attempt to close with wx.CallAfter.

```
import unittest
import wx

class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Test')
        wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Flintstones', 
                size=(340, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("White")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
        self.button = wx.Button(panel, id=-1, label='custom dlg', size=(75, 25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.create_dlg, self.button)
        self.msgbutton = wx.Button(panel, id=-1, label='wx message dlg', size=(75, 25))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.create_msgdlg, self.msgbutton)

    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def create_dlg(self, event):
        TEXT="specimens interpretations are saved"
        self.dlg = MyDialog(self)
        result = self.dlg.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            print("custom dlg: okay pressed")
        else:
            print("custom: okay not pressed")
        self.dlg.Destroy()

    def create_msgdlg(self, event):
        TEXT="specimens interpretations are saved"
        self.dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, caption="Saved",message=TEXT,style=wx.OK|wx.CANCEL)
        result = self.dlg.ShowModal()
        if result == wx.ID_OK:
            print("message dlg: okay pressed")
        else:
            print("message dlg: okay not pressed")
        self.dlg.Destroy()

class TestMyDialog(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = wx.App()
        self.frame = MyFrame(None,1)
        self.frame.Show()

    def tearDown(self):
        wx.CallAfter(self.app.Exit)
        self.app.MainLoop()

    def testDialog(self):
        evt = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId,self.frame.button.GetId())
        def clickOK():
            clickEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wx.ID_OK)
            self.frame.dlg.ProcessEvent(clickEvent)
        wx.CallAfter(clickOK)
        self.frame.ProcessEvent(evt)

    def testMsgDialog(self):
        evt = wx.CommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId,self.frame.msgbutton.GetId())
        def clickOK():
            clickEvent = wx.CommandEvent(wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wx.ID_OK)
            self.frame.dlg.ProcessEvent(clickEvent)
        wx.CallAfter(clickOK)
        self.frame.ProcessEvent(evt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19815382/4281182)

Comment: You could probably use `wx.UIActionSimulator`. See http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/UIActionSimulator.html for more information

Comment: @SelçukCihan I tried using a timer and I get no response when I run the same code calling clickOK in a separate thread that sleeps before calling it.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I should have mentioned in the description I am using wxpython 2.8.12.1 gtk2. As it was the stable version in the ubuntu repositories. `wx.UIActionSimulator` isn't introduced until 2.9.2. Also as this is on a project has a couple of devs using wxpython 2.8 through 3.0 I would like my solution to run on most in use versions of wxpython.

Comment: wxPython 3.0 is also considered a stable version. But if you're stuck with the very old 2.8 series, then you'll have to roll your own method. Or you might be able to use http://www.sikuli.org/