# Possible to use with statement with wx.DirDialog()

Tags: python, python-3.x, modal-dialog, wxpython

I have the following button event handler:

```
def select_source_folder(self, event):
     with wx.DirDialog(self.panel,message="Choose Source Directory" style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE):
         if wx.DirDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
              pass
```

I was reading on this page about `wx.FileDialog` and in the [example](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileDialog.html) it uses the `with` statement. I'm aware I'm using `wx.DirDialog` but is it possible to use the `with` statement with `wx.DirDialog`?

I get the following error when I try my code:

> TypeError: DirDialog.ShowModal(): first argument of unbound method
>   must have type 'DirDialog'

From [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790010/how-to-close-wx-dirdialog-programatically), it seems I would have t close and clean it up manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bug. You can submit bugs on wxPython's website here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues

Be sure to check that this hasn't already been reported before you do so though.

In the meantime, you can just subclass `wx.DirDialog` and make it work like a context manager. Here's an example:

```
import wx

class ContextDirDialog(wx.DirDialog):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.Destroy()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label='Choose Folder')
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.select_source_folder)

    def select_source_folder(self, event):
        with ContextDirDialog(self, message="Choose Source Directory",
                              style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE) as dlg:
            if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                print('You cancelled the dialog!')

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Contexts')
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You might also find the following article helpful:

- https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2015/10/22/wxpythons-context-managers/

Comment: Thanks, I've come across your blog before, I should have checked it first before asking. :D Bookmarked for next time.